# Can someone please explain why the answer is 0.5? -PHP code

Tags: php

```
<?php
$size = "size1";
  class Test {
    public $size1, $size2;
    function __construct($size1 = 10, $size2 = 5){
      $this->size1 = $size1;
      $this->size2 = $size2;
      $this->size = $size1 / $size2;
}
  }
  $test = new Test(20,40);
  echo $test->size;
?>
```

The result is 0.5, can someone explain why? I thought it would be 2 since the method its taking in the 2 variables of 10 and 5, but then it's creating a new object with the following parameters which override the values $size1 and $size2 ?

Comment: 20/40 = 0.5 : `$size1 / $size2`

Comment: These are default parameters `$size1 = 10, $size2 = 5`, If you dont pass any of the parameter then its default value will be used.

Answer (score 1):

`10` and `5` are just the default values for the constructor - if you pass something else - in this case `20` and `40`, the constructor will be called with this values instead.

The constructor is the method, which is everytime called, if you create an new instance of an object and named `__construct`. So if you write `new Test(20, 40)` you call the method `__construct` of class `Test` with the params `20` and `40`.

Answer (score 0):

With $test = new Test(20,40);  you are assigning 20 to $size1 and 40 to $size2. The answer is 20/40 = 0.5. If you want to use the default values [you specified for your parameters], use new Test(), yielding 20/10 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely correct.Because the parameters passed in the are default values they will only be used if you do not pass any parameter while making new objects like this

```
$test = new Test();
```